# mezzanine showing pages only when logged in

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I've got some trouble with my brand new mezzanine installation. After setting up mysql with UTF8 charset, migrating the model to the database and setting up a superuser for mezzanine I created a new page with some content that I wanted to show to my students.

You can visit it here: [fadenstrahl.de](http://fadenstrahl.de)
The page "Elektromagnetismus" is missing!

It shows up as long as I am logged in but it hides when i'm logged out. And the checkbox "login required" is not checked!

I was trying to set up this page as / (in the meta description)
and redirect the homepage to this page in the ursl.py by commenting this line:

```
# url("^$", direct_to_template, {"template": "index.html"}, name="home"),
```

and uncommenting this line:

```
url("^$", mezzanine.pages.views.page, {"slug": "/"}, name="home"),
```

I had to add this at the beginning:

```
import mezzanine.pages.views
```

I got the same problem. But because due to the problem, I get a 404 because there is no homepage anymore.

Here is the output from the shell:

```
    Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
    Not Found: /
    [12/Feb/2017 16:10:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1677
```

Why do I have to be logged in to see the content. I want it to be public.

Comment: Have you published it?

Comment: To expand on @BojanKogoj's comment, in the admin there is a checkbox on each page. It is not publicly available until selected and saved.

Answer (score 0):

@Bojan Kogoj
I have published it and also the time is correct. BUT you got me to the solution:
1. I published a new page and had the same problem.
2. But when a change the publish day to yesterday it works!

I think it might has something to do with wrong time zones.

Thanks a lot for this idea.